# Minecraft diagonal graphics glitches on Ubuntu 11.10 x64bits, not happening on Ubuntu 12 beta 2 x64bits

Tags: intel-graphics, minecraft

Minecraft has severe graphics glitches (diagonally split view on the minecraft window, half the image of the background and half minecraft.) it flashes sometimes..

I don't know if that is relevant but I read something on the openGL documentation about graphic images not being dividable by 4 or something, which causes the diagonal corruption of the final image.

So. I tested minecraft in Ubuntu 12 beta 2 (64bit) which did not have that graphical error.

I upgraded the kernel to the version Ubuntu 12 had (3.2), however same problem occurs.

I have Intel B800 processor, with intel hd graphics 2000 i presume. it doesn't tell on ark.intel.com website.
Using `lspci -v` outputs

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`

`Subsystem: Device 1b0a:2080

Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45

Memory at f5000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]

Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]

I/O ports at e000 [size=64]

Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]

Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-

Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2

Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features

Kernel driver in use: i915

Kernel modules: i915`

When minecraft is open, the ubuntu interface also lags, like text etc, buttons also split diagonally in half...
Its weird.

Comment: So you have both systems on the same computer? why don't you just wait those 8 days that are left until 12.04 gets final, and then you use 12.04?

Comment: Thought about waiting.. but the answer to the question is bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by installing intel hd graphics drivers from third party ppa source..

A great article about it here: [Updated & Optimized Ubuntu Free Graphics Drivers @ phoronix.com](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers)